# Query to show an alert to user when device is not connected to Internet

Tags: android

I want to show the message "No Internet Connection" if my app is not connected to the internet when the users are accessing. By default it shows "Page not found...(url)" . But I want to show a message to the user "To check the Internet Connection" if the device is not connected to Internet when accessing my app. Can anyone suggest me how to do this? Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

Make a seperate class named ConnectionDetector for detect availability of internet

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

    private Context _context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Activity context) {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length;)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    else {
                        showAlertDialog(_context, "No Internet Connection",
                                "You don't have internet connection.");
                        return false;
                    }

        }

        return false;
    }

    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Call this coce like this :

```
   ConnectionDetector connectionDetector = new ConnectionDetector(this);
    if (connectionDetector.isConnectingToInternet()) {
// do your stuff
                }
```